# EFS unmounted after some time

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mount, amazon-efs

I have a EFS mount to 2 Linux servers. Randomly one of them would get unmounted. Are there logs or any general issues with EFS that this could pertain to? This is the command I use to mount the EFS:

```
sudo mount -t nfs4 -o nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2 fs-xxxxxxx.efs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:/ /var/lib/emapi/static
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the volume to `/etc/fstab`?

Its likely being lost when the instance reboots.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/mount-fs-auto-mount-onreboot.html